# VS2008 Entity Framework The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection

Tags: visual-studio-2008, entity-framework

I am using entity framework with VS 2008. I am getting error "The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection."

This can be avoided by setting LazyLoadingEnable=false but it is supported by EF4 and .Net framework 4 vs2010

Is there any alternative for vs2008 to remove this error?

Comment: Where do you get this exception?

Answer (score 1):

if your queries against the objectcontext have a return type of IQueryable or IEnumerable, the data is not retrieved from the database until you enumerate it.

you will receive that error if you try to enumerate later, when the objectcontext is already disposed.

also have a look here:
[ASP.Net Entity Framework, objectcontext error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2884332/asp-net-entity-framework-objectcontext-error)