# make dropdown list of person

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

i have a model :

```
public  class person
 {
   public int id{get;set;}
   public string name{get;set;}
 }
```

how can i make a drop down list, from  list of person in mvc3 razor by this syntax : @Html.DropDownListFor(...) ?
what type must be my persons list?

sorry I'm new in mvc3

thanks all

Comment: possible duplicate of [Populating ASP.NET MVC DropDownList](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297399/populating-asp-net-mvc-dropdownlist)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    public class PersonModel
    {           
        public int SelectedPersonId { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Person> persons{ get; set; }
    }
    public class Person
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

then in the controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{        
    var model = new PersonModel{             
        persons= Enumerable.Range(1,10).Select(x=>new Person{

            Id=(x+1),
            Name="Person"+(x+1)                
        }).ToList()                     <--- here is the edit

    };
    return View(model);//make a strongly typed view
}
```

your view should look like this

```
@model Namespace.Models.PersonModel
<div>
   @Html.DropDownListFor(x=>x.SelectedPersonId,new SelectList(Model.persons,"Id","Name","--Select--"))
</div>
```

Comment: thanks a lot i test it but in line                                           Html.DropDownListFor(x=>x.SelectedPersonId,new    SelectList(Model.persons,"Id","Name","--Select--")) gave this error: The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.

Comment: it working with me... try it using `.ToList()` i'll update the answer in a bit

Comment: thanks but using mades that error if i remove using it works fine ,why with using that error happens?

            using (KCMDBEntities KCMDB = new KCMDBEntities())
            {
               
            }

Comment: here it is explained http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2884332/asp-net-entity-framework-objectcontext-error/2884343#2884343

Comment: thanks 3nigma you  help me very nice your sample was Very helpful.thanks a lot 3nigma

Answer (score 1):

You should translate that to a `List<SelectListItem>` if you want to use the build in MVC HtmlHelpers.

```
  @Html.DropDownFor(x => x.SelectedPerson, Model.PersonList)
```

Alternatively, you can simply make your own in the template:

```
<select id="select" name="select">
@foreach(var item in Model.PersonList)
{
   <option value="@item.id">@item.name</option>
}
</select>
```

Comment: i want to use @Html.DropDownListFor(...) what now?